# How should I add list data to Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
</Grid>
```

I would like to add the `TextBlock` from the list here.

[image: Grid with six rows and eight columns in the designer with its XAML code.]

ViewModel Code

[image: Code of the view model in Visual Studio.]

I try to use `ListBox`, but that's not what I want.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Serials}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding aaa}" Margin="20"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: ListBox with WrapPanel containing numbered items.]

I'll frame the grid and make pagination.
What I want is to center the `TextBlock` in the grid.

How should I do it?

Comment: I think that it is unclear, what you want to do. Please describe _in detail_, what the expected result is? Do you want your items arranged like in a `Grid` with fixed rows and columns like in your first example (6x8)? What does "What I want is TextBlock in the grid center."? Do you mean you want to center the text in each grid cell?

Comment: @thatguy yes,You understand what I mean,I want  items arranged like in a Grid with fixed rows and columns, center the text in each grid cell,My English is not very good. I'm sorry to trouble you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind a list with a `Grid` like layout, use a `ListBox` with a [`UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.UniformGrid);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) as items panel. Specify a property in [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0), then you do not have to create a redundant `DataTemplate` to bind `aaa`. Assign an [`ItemsContainerStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.UniformGrid);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to adapt the content alignments to center the content.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Serials}" DisplayMemberPath="aaa">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="8"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

You can of course bind the `Rows` and `Columns` of the `UniformGrid`, to adapt the grid dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your good advice！

Answer (score 2):

The approach here is wrong, instead of grid you can simply use ListView, it will dynamically use the space and display in grid view.

We populate a list of our own User objects, each user having a name and an age. The data binding process happens automatically as soon as we assign the list to the ItemsSource property of the ListView, but the result is a bit discouraging:

Here is the sample code :

Xaml :

```
<Grid>
  <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding"></ListView>
</Grid>
```

c#

```
public partial class ListViewDataBindingSample : Window
 {
    public ListViewDataBindingSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
        lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
    }
 }

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have used listview and listbox ,But it's not what I want,You can look at the code I edited

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused between `Grid` and `Listview`.

Why do you want to use both?

Try a Horizontal Listview.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Because I want to make a queuing software. A table contains about 50 data, and the extra data will be made into pages,,Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

XAML code

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="gridMain">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "I'm here!";

Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 2);
gridMain.Children.Add(textBlock);
```